# Using Spring's theme resolvers and themes with a Thymeleaf template

Tags: spring, themes, thymeleaf

I would like to use Spring theme resolvers' feature (see: [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-themeresolver-defining)) in my Thymeleaf template.

**What is the Thymeleaf's equivalent to the spring:theme JSP tag?**

See JSP code sample below:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<html>
   <head>
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="<spring:theme code='styleSheet'/>" type="text/css"/>
   </head>
   <body style="background=<spring:theme code='background'/>">
      ...
   </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think this was the case at the time that you asked your question, but the current version of thymeleaf-spring3 (2.0.18 as of this writing) has as part of the [SpringStandard dialect](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Thymeleaf-Spring3.html#the-springstandard-dialect) a themes function, which can be used like this:

```
<body th:style="'background-color: ' + ${#themes.code('backgroundColor')}">
```